# How filter with Mongo and on multiple field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, filter, find

I search how to work this case with mongo and mongoose.

I have this JSON

```
    [
      { title: 'foo', description :'bar', requirements: 'fooBar'},
      { title: 'baz', description :'foo', requirements: 'BarFoo'},
      { title: 'bar', description : 'baz', requirements: 'BazBaz' }
    ]
```

My goals is to research with the keyword 'bar', in priority , on the field 'title' then 'description' and finally , on the field 'requirements'.

case 1: keyword: 'bar' search (contain the keyword)

OUTPUT:

```
[
  { title: 'bar', description :'baz', requirements: 'BazBaz'},
  { title: 'foo', description : 'bar', requirements: 'fooBar' },
  { title: 'baz', description :'foo', requirements: 'BarFoo'},
]
```

case 2: keyword: 'fooBar'

OUTPUT

```
[
  { title: 'foo', description :'bar', requirements: 'fooBar'},
]
```

case 3: keyword: 'foo'

OUTPUT

```
    [
      { title: 'foo', description :'bar', requirements: 'fooBar'},
      { title: 'baz', description :'foo', requirements: 'BarFoo'},
    ]
```

I use this aggregation but didn't expect the result:

```
$or: [
  {
    title:
    {
      $regex: req.query.keyword,
      $options: 'i'
    }
  },
  {
    description:
      {
        $regex: req.query.keyword,
        $options: 'i'
      }
  }
],
```

Thanks to help

Answer (score 0):

I've tried, not an aggregation but a `find()` with the `$or` operator.

Here's the data sample:

```
> db.mycollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d2b9a0c25b1266860ada3"), "title" : "foo", "description" : "bar", "requirements" : "fooBar" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d2ba50c25b1266860ada4"), "title" : "baz", "description" : "foo", "requirements" : "BarFoo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d2bae0c25b1266860ada5"), "title" : "bar", "description" : "baz", "requirements" : "BazBaz" }
```

And there's the query:

```
> db.mycollection.find({
    $or: [ 
      { 
        title: { $regex: "bar", $options: "i"}
      },
      { 
        description: { $regex: "bar", $options: "i" }
      } 
    ]
})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d2b9a0c25b1266860ada3"), "title" : "foo", "description" : "bar", "requirements" : "fooBar" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d2bae0c25b1266860ada5"), "title" : "bar", "description" : "baz", "requirements" : "BazBaz" }
```